# unity of subring different from the unity of ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $n=2k$, where $k>1$ is an odd integer. Find a nontrivial subring $S$ of $\mathbb Z_n$ where $S$ has a unity different from the unity of $\mathbb Z_n$.

In regards to multiplication, wouldn't the unity always be 1? I'm confused how the unity would be different since we're dealing with integers.

Let's say I created S={3k}, then the unity is still 1. Could I do S={3k+1} to shift all the integers?

Comment: $1$ is not in your $S$, so how can it be the unity?

Comment: Sorry, I think I meant S={Zmod6) where n=3k.

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb Z_{10}$, the subring $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$ has identity $6$, and the subring $\{0,5\}$ has identity $5$.

More generally, the Chinese remainder theorem says that $\mathbb Z/(2k)\cong \mathbb Z/(2)\times \mathbb Z/(k)$ as rings when $k$ is odd. The subring corresponding to $\mathbb Z/(2)$ looks like $\{0, k\}$ and $k$ is the identity, since $k^2-k=0\pmod{2k}$ (because $k|k$ and $2|k-1$).

It follows automatically that the identity for the other ring is $1-k$.

Comment: If $R$ is commutative and unitary and $e∈R$ is a non-trivial idempotent, then $Re\subset R$ is a proper subring which has identity, namely $e$, and $1\notin Re$. (All examples above are particular cases of this one.)